# Invalid Query C#

Tags: c#

today i wrote my second Code in C#
why wont it work? the code ist (as it seems) correct!

error code: InvalidQuery

Code:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          GetComponent("Win32_Processor", "Name");
        Console.Read();
        Console.ReadKey();
      }

    private static void GetComponent(string hwclass, string syntax)
    {
    ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher ("root\\CIMV2","SELECT * FROM" + hwclass);
    foreach(ManagementObject mj in mos.Get())
       {
           Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(mj[syntax]));
       }


    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use DEBUG feature in VS?

Comment: Eh, try to add *space* after the `FROM`: `"root\\CIMV2","SELECT * FROM " + hwclass)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, use *formatting* or *string interpolation* (C# 6.0+) to avoid syntax errors:

```
private static void GetComponent(string hwclass, string syntax) {
  //DONE: keep query readable
  string query = 
    $@"select * 
         from {hwclass}"; // <- you've missed space here

  //DONE: wrap IDisposable into using
  using (ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", query)) {
    foreach(ManagementObject mj in mos.Get())
      Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(mj[syntax]));
  }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't have put it better myself. +1 for the tip with formatting and string interpolation.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a space after the "FROM":

```
("root\\CIMV2","SELECT * FROM" + hwclass);
```

Change to:

```
("root\\CIMV2","SELECT * FROM " + hwclass);
```